# Filtering data in a JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an JSON array like this:

```
json = [{
 "a":"ABABABAB",
 "b":30,
 "c":"available"
},
{
 "a":"A",
 "b":30,
 "c":"unavailable"
},
{
 "a":"AB",
 "b":29,
 "c":"available"
},
{
 "a":"ABAABACDA",
 "b":29,
 "c":"available"
},
{
 "a":"ABAABACDA",
 "b":29,
 "c":"available"
}];
```

1. I have to filter the JSON data out based on following two conditions:
   a. The values of "a" should be unique,
   b. The count of values of "a" should be `>= 3`; (e.g: `ABABABAB = 8`)
2. Fetch the length of each string in the filtered array and sum it. (e.g: `["ABABABA", "ABABA"]` --> 12)

What I've done so far..

a. for `a` should be unique:

```
unique_a = [];
for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {

  if (unique_a.indexOf(json[i].a) === -1) {
    unique_a.push(json[i].a);
  }
}
```

b. for `>= 3`:

```
var sort_3 = unique_a.filter(el => el.a.length >= 3);
```

Comment: you can use underscore.js for that

Comment: I actually have sorted the first point. Sorting out the array. Got stuck in doing the sum of all "a.length"

Comment: Array and filtering questions are fairly common here on Stack Overflow, have you searched for similar questions?

Comment: @PrathapG.. I've edited the question with what I've done so far.. please check it once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the total of all `a.length`, you can use a simple `forEach()` loop and add the lengths to a variable:

```
var total = 0;

unique_a.forEach(function(u) {
  total += u.length;
});

console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use JS [Array.map](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp) [Array.fileter](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp) [Array.reduce](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp) to achiveby chaining the methods

```js
function countUniqueTextLengths(arr) {

  return arr.map((a) => a.a).filter((a, i, ar) => ar.indexOf(a) == i && a.length > 4).reduce((t, v) => t + v.length, 0)
}

//optimized
function countUniqueTextLengths_2(arr) {

  var u = [],
    c = 0;
  arr.forEach(element => {
    if (u.indexOf(element.a) === -1 && element.a.length > 4) {
      u.push(element.a);
      c += element.a.length;
    }
  });
  return c;
}

var json = [{
    "a": "ABABABAB",
    "b": 30,
    "c": "available"
  },
  {
    "a": "A",
    "b": 30,
    "c": "unavailable"
  },
  {
    "a": "AB",
    "b": 29,
    "c": "available"
  },
  {
    "a": "ABAABACDA",
    "b": 29,
    "c": "available"
  },
  {
    "a": "ABAABACDA",
    "b": 29,
    "c": "available"
  }
];

console.log(countUniqueTextLengths(json))
console.log(countUniqueTextLengths_2(json))
```

Comment: This is a good solution but keep in mind that all of those (`map()`, `filter()`, and `reduce()`) have to make a full pass through the array - you're looping through three times. Sometimes it's best to see if/where you can combine these iterations. If you don't see an easy way, you could even use a simple `forEach()` and write out all the steps in there, and then see where you can combine them into one iteration method (like `reduce()`)  :)

Comment: @TylerRoper yes, I added a new function to looping single time.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done in a few simple, chained steps:

1. `reduce()` the array to apply our filters (unique, and `length > 3`)
2. `join()` the results of that into a single string
3. Get the `.length` of that string

```js
var json = [{ "a": "ABABABAB", "b": 30, "c": "available" }, { "a": "A", "b": 30, "c": "unavailable" }, { "a": "AB", "b": 29, "c": "available" }, { "a": "ABAABACDA", "b": 29, "c": "available" }, { "a": "ABAABACDA", "b": 29, "c": "available" }];

let result = json
  .reduce( (a,i) => !a.includes(i.a) && i.a.length > 3 ? [...a, i.a] : a , [])
  .join("")
  .length;
  
console.log(result);
```

---

**Explanation**

**1.** [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) takes our existing array items (`i`) and creates a new one from them (`a`).

```
.reduce( (a,i) => 
   !a.includes(i.a) && i.a.length > 3  //If not yet in our resulting array and length > 3
   ? [...a, i.a]  //Add it to the resulting array
   : a            //Else, leave the array alone
 , [])            //The initial value of our resulting array
```

This leaves us with:

```
[
  "ABABABAB",
  "ABAABACDA"
]
```

**2.** We can then `.join("")` to combine it into a single string:

```
"ABABABABABAABACDA"
```

**3.** And finally, `.length` to give us the amount of letters in that string:

```
17
```

Answer (score -1):

using `lodash` https://lodash.com/

```js
var json = [{
 "a":"ABABABAB",
 "b":30,
 "c":"available"
},
{
 "a":"A",
 "b":30,
 "c":"unavailable"
},
{
 "a":"AB",
 "b":29,
 "c":"available"
},
{
 "a":"ABAABACDA",
 "b":29,
 "c":"available"
},
{
 "a":"ABAABACDA",
 "b":29,
 "c":"available"
}];


var uniq = _.uniqBy(json, 'a');

var result = _.filter(uniq, function(value, key) {
  return value.a.length >= 3;
});
//console.log(result);

var lengths = _.map(_.map(result, 'a'), function(str){
 return str.length
});

var sum = _.reduce(lengths, (a, b) => a + b, 0);
console.log(sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```